# Comparing three or more things

Tags: grammar

To compare two things, I would use:

> りんごのほうがみかんより美味しいです。

i.e. noun のほうがnoun よりadjective

But how can I say, "Out of these five fruits, apples are the most delicious"?
Or "Out of Seoul, Tokyo, and Shanghai, Shanghai is the biggest"?

Answer (score 5):

> この五種類の果物の{中/うち}で、りんごが{一番/最も}おいしいです。
>   ソウルや、東京、上海の{中/うち}で上海が{一番/最も}大きいです。

Comment: Can `のほうが` still be used?

Comment: @Flaw No. That is only for comparing two things.

Comment: also, can `ましだ` be used?

Comment: @Flaw I think you can use it like `一番ましだ`.